# Python 3. - Why aren't my logical operators ('and', 'or') not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning Python and the logical `and` doesn't seem to work for example only `myName` needs to be 'Chris' and `myVar` could be 5 and it will still print 'Chris is great'.

I have also tried using an `or` which didn't seem to follow any logic either.
In addition, I even tried `myVar != 0` in the if statement and this didn't make any difference!

Just to confirm, I definitely know how `and` and `or` affect the if condition.

```
print("Hello world")
myName = input("What is your name? ") 
print("Your name is",myName)
myVar = input("Enter a number: ")
if(myName == 'Chris' and myVar == 0):
    print("Chris is great")
elif(myName=='Bob'):
    print("Bob is ok!")
else:
    print("who are you?")
```

Thank you to anyone who can help - my guess is it has something to do with how I have configured python..? I am definitely running a .py file though.

Comment: myVar will be a string, so you are comparing `'0' == 0 ` which is false here

Comment: "only myName needs to be 'Chris' and myVar could be 5 and it will still print 'Chris is great'." No, it will print 'who are you?'. Please clarify what your problem is or post code that actually reproduces it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that `input` creates a string from the input. You need to convert `myVar` into an integer with `int()`.

```
print("Hello world")
myName = input("What is your name? ") 
print("Your name is",myName)
myVar = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # myVar is an int now
if (myName == 'Chris' and myVar == 0):
    print("Chris is great")
elif(myName=='Bob'):
    print("Bob is ok!")
else:
    print("who are you?")
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much - the tutorial I was following said that in python there was never any need to declare the type of a variable but is it true that you would always have to in cases like this?

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @chris_1097 this isn't declaring the type of the variable, it's actually changing what type it is.

Comment: @chris_1097, what Rob Watts said. You aren't declaring it an int, you are calling the int() function on it as input always returns a string. So Python reads the input and returns a string. You are then calling the int() function to convert it to an int. It only works if an integer literal is the input, otherwise the program will crash if not handled.

Comment: Understood. I will find an up-to-date tutorial that explains 3.x! Thank you for all your help

Comment: no matter with the tutorial. The statement "you will not have to declare what type the variable has" is perfectly ok. Seems you just mixed it up with that `"0"` of course have a type (`str`) and that type is assigned to any variable, e.g. `myVar`, together with the value `"0"`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `input` returns a `str`, but in Python 2, `input` can return an `int`.

So, your if statement works fine.

```
>>> myVar = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 0
>>> type(myVar)
str
```

Therefore `myVar == 0` is never true, but `myVar == '0'` is.

So, either quote the `0` or cast `input` to an `int` like

```
myVar = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

But, beware that if you don't type a number, this will throw an error, which is why you should just quote the `0`, in my opinion (unless you actually need a number at some point).

Comment: Does this make '0' a character type value? because myVar is a string?

Comment: `char` is not a datatype in Python, only `str`, so `'0'` is a string of length 1.